# Play video in full screen actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, fullscreen

I am building an website and i want this website to have an video in the background. I have done the part where the flash is behind everything but i can not play this video in fullscreen. 
How can i play flv video on fullscreen with actionscript2.0. I dont need a button for this video to go fullscreen it simply needs to start on fullscreen.

Answer (score 3):

You have to embed your player setting `allowFullScreen="true"`.  Then in you AS2 code, set

```
Stage.displayState="fullScreen";
```

Note that there should be "" around "fullScreen".

You cannot start fullScreen mode, if the player is embedded using `windowMode="transparent"` or `windowMode="opaque"`.  Also, the displayState cannot be set to "fullScreen" without user input, if the SWF is running in a browser. So you will have to have a button or key listener.

Check out this [blog entry on fullScreen mode](http://www.funky-monkey.nl/blog/2007/09/10/fullscreen-mode-in-as2/).

Answer (score 1):

Stage 1
Layer 1
Frame 1
Set Action

```
Stage.displayState=fullScreen;
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code for playing the video with actionscript 2.0 and this fullscreen line ?

Comment: it seams i am not doing that in the right way and the video is not displaying good.